# Meteor React createContainer rerender

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Hi guys so I have a container like this

```
export default createContainer((props) => {
  console.log('createContainer')
  const {id} = props.params
  Meteor.subscribe('items')
  return {item: Items.findOne(id)}
}, Editor)
```

Inside the `Editor` component I call a meteor method and do some changes to the `item` I find in the container. Thus shouldn't the createContainer rerender and pass the item as a prop again, so that I get my newly made changes from the db? Or am I missing something here? Is there anyway I can make it rerun?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the problem was not in this.
The problem was that I was putting my value inside the textarea instead of using value.